# Primefaces Megamenu keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces, keyboard

I'm using primefaces megamenu, but I can't navigate using the keyboard. I guess its not implemented.

But if I would want to implement keyboard actions myself in a separate js file, what is the way to hook up with this megamenu?

Thank you!

Comment: Best way is to download the PF source, check out the existing js code, improve it, use it and file a patch

Comment: I guess, I'll do it like this. May be someone has some experience?

Comment: other menu components most likely have some keyboard navigation. That might server as an example